# Finding the $n$th term in a 2nd order linear recursive sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic-progressions

$\begin{gathered}a_{n}=a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}\\ a_{1}=3\\ a_{5}=55\\ a_{{}6}=?\\ \end{gathered}$

I've tried solving it through the Fibonacci sequence, but it didn't work either. I am required to find the sixth term in this sequence (recursive). Help appreciated.

Comment: Let $a_6 = b$, then $a_4 = 55+b$, $a_3 = (55+b)+55$, ..., represent $a_1$ in terms of $b$.

Comment: Set $x=a_{2}$. We know $a_{1}$, so using the recurrence with $n=1$ we can find $a_{3}$ in terms of $x$. Then using the recurrence again (twice) we can find $a_{4}$ and $a_{5}$ in terms of $x$. Putting $a_{5}$ equal to 55, we can find $x$ and finish. (A pity this question has now been given complete answers. Doesn't leave much for the OP to do.)

Answer (score 1):

$$a_1=a_2+a_3$$$$=2a_3+a_4$$$$=2(a_4+a_5)+a_4$$$$=3a_4+2a_5$$$$=3(a_5+a_6)+2a_5$$$$=5a_5+3a_6$$
As per question,$$\therefore a_1=5a_5+3a_6$$$$\implies a_6=\frac{3-5(55)}{3}=-90.67$$

Answer (score 0):

While the defining recurrence relation bears a resemblance to that for the Fibonacci sequence, expressing it as $ \ a_{n \ + \ 2} \ = \  a_{n } - a_{n \ + \ 1} \ \ , $ it has a somewhat different character.  Since we are given that $ \ a_1 \ = \ 3 \ \ , \ \ a_5 \ = \ 55 \ \ , \ $ one might suspect that *this* sequence is one with alternating signs in order for the subtraction of terms to produce an increase from the first to the fifth term.

An alternative to the method employed by **AltercatingCurrent** is to sum  successive relations to obtain
$$ a_3 \ \ = \ \ 3 \ - \ a_2 \ \ , \ \  a_4 \ \ = \ \ a_2 \ - \ a_3 \ \ , \ \ 55 \ \ = \ \ a_3 \ - \ a_4 \ \  $$ $$  \Rightarrow \ \  a_3 \ + \ a_4 \ + \ 55 \ \ = \ \ 3 \ - \ a_4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a_3 \ + \ 2·a_4 \ \ = \ \ -52 \ \ . $$

We also have $ \ 55 \ = \ a_3 - a_4 \ \Rightarrow \ a_3 \ = \ 55 + a_4 \ \ , \ $ and thus
$$    ( \ 55  \ + \ a_4 \ ) \ + \ 2·a_4 \ \ = \  -52  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a_4 \ \ = \ \ -\frac{52 \ + \ 55}{3} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{107}{3} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ a_6 \ \ = \ \ a_4 \ - \ 55 \ \   = \ \    -\frac{107}{3} \ - \ 55 \ \ = \ \ -\frac{107 \ + \ 165}{3} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{272}{3} \ \ . $$

With a bit of computation, we can now establish the first six terms of the sequence as $ \ 3 \ \ , \ \ -\frac{49}{3} \ \ , \ \ \frac{58}{3} \ \ , \ \ -\frac{107}{3} \ \ , \ \  55 \ \ , \ \  -\frac{272}{3} \ \ . \ $  (I have not investigated this all that thoroughly, but it looks like the ratio of successive terms gradually converges to $ \ -\phi \ \ . \ ) $

The Fibonacci sequence takes seven terms to span from $ \ 3 \ $ to $ \ 55 \ \ , \ $ so it doesn't seem like there is a simple way to use it to resolve the question for this sequence.  (Perhaps there is a Binet-like formula for computing its terms directly, but that would take rather more work to determine than is presented in the answers here.)